# MVC6 - if(checkbox ticked) then strikethrough

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I've got the following code:

```
<table class="table">
@foreach (var item in Model.AllTasks)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TaskDetails)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

I'd like to be able to read whether the checkbox is ticked, and if so apply a strikethrough to the TaskDetails. At the moment I'm struggling to find any simple way of achieving this.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want this to happen dynamically upon checking/unchecking or to apply it initially when loading the markup from the server based on the value of the checkbox?

Comment: Dynamically, good question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `jquery` you can do it easily like following code snippet.

```js
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $(this).parent().next().css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
  } else {
    $(this).parent().next().css('text-decoration', 'none');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td><td> Box 1 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td><td> Box 2 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td><td> Box 3 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td><td> Box 4 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a bool property to your model to determine if a task is complete:

```
public bool IsComplete { get;set; }
```

Then in your view you could do the following:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.AllTasks)
{
   @:<tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox"/>
      </td>
      <td>
      @if (item.IsComplete)
      {
      @:<strike>
      }
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TaskDetals)
      @if (item.IsComplete)
      {
       @:</strike>
      }
    </td>
  @:</tr>
}
```

This simply checks the status then conditionally prints the `strike` tag.

**[Working fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/I5hji5)**

If you would like to do this via javascript, as they check the box you could use the following code:

```
  $("[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
     $(this).parent().next().wrapInner("<strike></strike>")
    }
   });
```

This dynamically wraps the text with the `strike` tag.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oLemh8rr/)**